# GradientDrawable border textview croped

Tags: android, textview, gradientdrawable

As you can see on the picture below, I put a GradientDrawable as background of a textview.

The result is weird : the text is croped.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsSra.png)

And there is the code :

```
GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
    border.setColor(0x00FFFFFF);
    border.setStroke(1,Color.GRAY);
    border.setCornerRadius(size);

    EditText surname = new EditText(this);
    surname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    surname.setBackground(border);
    surname.setTypeface(Stats.fontRegular);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lps = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, size_x);
    surname.setLayoutParams(lps);
    view.addView(surname);
```

If you know a way to uncrop the text it will be very usefull for me :)

Comment: What's `size_x` and why are you setting it as height? That's cropping the text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works :

When you use a EditText, it seems that there are some paddings inside the view. So you can 'disable' them using

```
EditText.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the gravity with this XML code:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/**yourstringname**"
/>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't use XML because I set almost every parameter of views programmatically. And you can see in the Java that I already try to change the gravity

Comment: Try to change this lane of code: 

surname.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
border.setColor(0x00FFFFFF);
border.setStroke(1,Color.GRAY);
border.setCornerRadius(size);
border.setSize(450, 150);
```